# OS X 10.8 seems to break printer communications

Tags: macos, printing

Anyone using a Kodak ESP 7250 with OS X 10.8?  Everything worked fine until I upgraded to 10.8. I have two computers and they both systematically stopped printing and scanning immediately after updating OS X.

- I've tried Kodak support a few times but they are absolutely NO help.
- I've installed the latest updates for printer and computer.
- I have followed Kodak's troubleshooting steps.
- I have tried USB and WiFi.
- I have played with my firewall.

Nothing. Just thought I would throw out a message here and see if anyone has had similar issues that got passed it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me with my Epson after upgrading to Mountain Lion. Not for a while did I realize, I was *not* following Epson's onsite directions to the letter, and when I did, everything began to work just fine.